# How can i Delete a form in django.so, the data in for in database will be deleted

Tags: python, python-2.7, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

in my html:

```
 <form action="/smartlogis/result_material/{{form.DBR_No.value}}/" method="POST">
    {{form.as_ul}}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /></form>
 <form action="/smartlogis/result_material/{{form.DBR_No.value}}/" method="GET">   

  <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

views.py:

def Matedit1(request,DBR_No):

```
f = Movement_In.objects.get(DBR_No=DBR_No)
if request.method == 'POST':

    form = Movement_ReceiptForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=f) 
    if form.is_valid():

        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
else:
    print "ahj"
    if request.method == 'GET':
        print "dsfsf"
        form = Movement_ReceiptForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=f)
        if request.POST.get('delete'):
            form.delete()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/smartlogis/matdelete.html/')
```

And now While i am clicking the delete button it is going into the else loop but form is not deleteing. and it directly going to HttpResponseRedirect

Comment: You absolutely should **not** use a GET request to delete items from your database.

Answer (score 0):

Your request can not be both a GET and a POST request so the delete statement can't be called.  Also if you wanted to delete "f" you would want

```
f.delete()
```

But again to reiterate this would not even be called.  The fact that it is not raising the error that delete() is not defined on a form or model form is due to the fact that this code can't be called under any condition.